# xarray: how to structure dataset

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I have a dataset of Sentinel 2 images with Red and Green bands, from ascending and descending orbits, over a specific time period. I have been playing around with xarray, as it seems like the right tool for the job, but I cannot find a logical way to arrange my data for easy query.

I considered a separate DataArray for each orbit, but not all orbits have the same number of data points so the dataset won't initialise. I then considered to have different bands in the data_vars of the dataset, but I am not sure how to format this with the orbit information then. Some attributes of the data are listed below, I'd appreciate some ideas on what a good way to represent this in XArray Dataset is.

- Every time step has at least one image with 2 bands
- A time step can have multiple images, each with a different orbit
- The image x,y dimensions are always the same

I need the following queries:
- Get all timesteps for a specific orbit and/or band
- Get all images in a time range
- Get all images in a time range, further filtered by band or orbit.

Thanks for the help